# Missing Quick Add item from Azure Boards with Custom Board Levels

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a set of custom boards that mirror the default SCRUM boards, so that I can work with different Work Items then the rest of our project.

In the below image, I can quickly add a Project to an Organization (not shown), or a Task to a Phase by clicking the little + on the left hand side. However, that + is missing from the Project, so I am not able to easily link a Phase to a Project.

[Screenshot of Azure Backlog with missing + button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFCIm.png)

However, if I switch to a board of a team using the default WIT, then I am able to quickly add those together.

I have read through the documentation for Azure Devops but I am not able to determine why it is missing.

Edit:

Here is a copy of how the process is currently setup, I have them setup in paralle with similar colours. So Organizations is comparable to the default Epics, Projects with Goal. From what I can tell, everything seems to be set correctly and I am just missing some other little check box.
[Devops Process](https://i.imgur.com/28rzkKv.png)

Comment: Hi @mz3ns, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below and may I know if it works for you?

Comment: Hi @mz3ns, If the answer works for you, you may consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may help others with similar concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared how you define the backlog levels in your custom process. Assuming that you have defined the backlog level as below, where the `Level 1` includes `Organization`,  `Level 2` includes `Project`,  `Backlog items` includes `Phase`,
[image]

I can create new `Phase` with the help of the `+` button in front of a `Project`.
[image]

Please check if you have defined the work item type `Phase` under the level of `Backlog items`
[image]

### **UPDATED**

Based on your update, I can reproduce the issue, when there is no enabled work item type **directly beneath** the backlog level `Consultant Projects`. (The work item type of `Epic` on the `Epics` level is disabled in your screenshot.)
[image]

Even `Epic` is enabled, you can only add new `Epic` items with the `+` button in front of a `Project` item, because it is the work item on the backlog level directly beneath `Consultant Projects` level.
[image]

Per your original expectation to add new `phase` items with the `+` button in front of a `Project` item, if you expect `phase` to stay as a requirement backlog, you should modify your backlog levels of this process like below and make sure there is no other backlog level between `Consultant Projects` and `Backlog Items`
[image]

Hope the analysis could help resolve your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for having a look!

I believe I have the process setup correctly https://i.imgur.com/28rzkKv.png 

However, if it is an issue with using two custom backlog levels (Organization & Project) I can revert to using the standard ones, I am only using the custom ones for clarity of what they represented since we my teams work is professional services not development and we are using DevOps since we can cross-link to our development items easily to track.

Comment: Hi there, Thx for the response. I have updated my answer accordingly. If it can help resolve your query, you may consider accepting it, which may help others with similar concerns. Happy weekend & cheers~